# My AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver and Service doesn't start

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, intentservice

I can't seem these to get up and running:

```
    public class BackgroundSyncService extends IntentService {

    public BackgroundSyncService() {
        super("SchedulingService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("asd-service", "lol");

        BackgroundSyncBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
    public class BackgroundSyncBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent service = new Intent(context, BackgroundSyncService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context){

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, BackgroundSyncBroadcastReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                0, 5000, alarmIntent);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BackgroundSyncBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

Third class:

```
public class BackgroundSyncBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

BackgroundSyncBroadcastReceiver service = new BackgroundSyncBroadcastReceiver();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        service.setAlarm(context);
    }
}
```

}

Manifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".BackgroundSyncBroadcastReceiver"/>

    <receiver android:name=".BackgroundSyncBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".BackgroundSyncService"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yeah, I forgot to start it from the acivity...

```
 BackgroundSyncBroadcastReceiver service = new BackgroundSyncBroadcastReceiver();
service.setAlarm(this);
```

Stupid mistake.

Comment: please accept this answer to get this question off the "unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Your receiver for BOOT_COMPLETED will not be allowed to fire until your app has been manually started by the user one time. This is a security feature to prevent apps from running without the user knowing about them.

Comment: I exited app and launched it again manually from device. Still no luck :/

Comment: Now sometimes it's working, sometime not - I figured out that restarting device helps a little, but it shouldn't work that way. Can that `if` statement in `BackgroundSyncBootReceiver` be the blocker here? What happens if I just let it go without any conditions?